# CUDA byte atomic operation to cause only one thread to act

Tags: cuda, atomic, gpu-shared-memory

I am writing a CUDA program which has an array defined in the shared memory. What I need to do is to allow only one thread to write each index in this array, i. e. the first thread to reach this write instruction should change its value but any other threads either in the same warp or next warps should read the written value.

Here is the code snippet:

```
char* seq_copied = seqs + (njobNew * halfLength); //this is the shared memory array
if (seq_copied[seq_1_index] == false) { //here is the condition that I need to check with only one thread
    seq_copied[seq_1_index] = true; //and this is the write that should be written by only one thread
    printf("copy seq_shared seq_1_index = %d,  block = %d \n", seq_1_index, blockIdx.x);
}
```

What is happening now is that all threads in the warp executes these exact sequence of instructions, thus the remaining code in the if condition is executed 32 times. I need to execute it only once.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`atomicCAS()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomiccas) for this.  It does an atomic Compare-And-Swap operation.

This function will test a variable, and if it matches a certain condition (say, false) it will replace it with another value (say, true).  It will do all these things atomically, i.e. without the possibility of interruption.

The return value of the atomic function gives us useful information in this case.  If the return value is false for the above example, then we can be certain that it was replaced with true.  We can also be certain that we were the "first" thread to run into this condition, and all other threads doing a similar operation will have a return value of true, not false.

Here's a worked example:

```
$ cat t327.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void k(){

  __shared__ int flag;
  if (threadIdx.x == 0) flag = 0;
  __syncthreads();

  int retval = atomicCAS(&flag, 0, 1);
  printf("thread %d saw flag as %d\n", threadIdx.x, retval);
  // could do if statement on retval here
}


int main(){

  k<<<1,32>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t327 t327.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t327
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
thread 0 saw flag as 0
thread 1 saw flag as 1
thread 2 saw flag as 1
thread 3 saw flag as 1
thread 4 saw flag as 1
thread 5 saw flag as 1
thread 6 saw flag as 1
thread 7 saw flag as 1
thread 8 saw flag as 1
thread 9 saw flag as 1
thread 10 saw flag as 1
thread 11 saw flag as 1
thread 12 saw flag as 1
thread 13 saw flag as 1
thread 14 saw flag as 1
thread 15 saw flag as 1
thread 16 saw flag as 1
thread 17 saw flag as 1
thread 18 saw flag as 1
thread 19 saw flag as 1
thread 20 saw flag as 1
thread 21 saw flag as 1
thread 22 saw flag as 1
thread 23 saw flag as 1
thread 24 saw flag as 1
thread 25 saw flag as 1
thread 26 saw flag as 1
thread 27 saw flag as 1
thread 28 saw flag as 1
thread 29 saw flag as 1
thread 30 saw flag as 1
thread 31 saw flag as 1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Responding to a question in the comments, we could extend this to a `char` sized flag by creating an arbitrary atomic operation modeled after the `double atomicAdd()` function given in [the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions).  The basic idea is that we will perform an atomicCAS using a supported data size (e.g. `unsigned`) and we will convert the needed operation to effectively support a `char` size.  This is done by converting the `char` address to a suitably-aligned `unsigned` address, and then doing shifting of the `char` quantity to line up in the appropriate byte position in the `unsigned` value.

Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t327.cu
#include <stdio.h>
__device__ char my_char_atomicCAS(char *addr, char cmp, char val){
  unsigned *al_addr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned *> (((unsigned long long)addr) & (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCULL));
  unsigned al_offset = ((unsigned)(((unsigned long long)addr) & 3)) * 8;
  unsigned mask = 0xFFU;
  mask <<= al_offset;
  mask = ~mask;
  unsigned sval = val;
  sval <<= al_offset;
  unsigned old = *al_addr, assumed, setval;
  do {
        assumed = old;
        setval = assumed & mask;
        setval |= sval;
        old = atomicCAS(al_addr, assumed, setval);
    } while (assumed != old);
  return (char) ((assumed >> al_offset) & 0xFFU);
}

__global__ void k(){

  __shared__ char flag[1024];
  flag[threadIdx.x] = 0;
  __syncthreads();

  int retval = my_char_atomicCAS(flag+(threadIdx.x>>1), 0, 1);
  printf("thread %d saw flag as %d\n", threadIdx.x, retval);
}


int main(){
  k<<<1,32>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t327 t327.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t327
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
thread 0 saw flag as 0
thread 1 saw flag as 1
thread 2 saw flag as 0
thread 3 saw flag as 1
thread 4 saw flag as 0
thread 5 saw flag as 1
thread 6 saw flag as 0
thread 7 saw flag as 1
thread 8 saw flag as 0
thread 9 saw flag as 1
thread 10 saw flag as 0
thread 11 saw flag as 1
thread 12 saw flag as 0
thread 13 saw flag as 1
thread 14 saw flag as 0
thread 15 saw flag as 1
thread 16 saw flag as 0
thread 17 saw flag as 1
thread 18 saw flag as 0
thread 19 saw flag as 1
thread 20 saw flag as 0
thread 21 saw flag as 1
thread 22 saw flag as 0
thread 23 saw flag as 1
thread 24 saw flag as 0
thread 25 saw flag as 1
thread 26 saw flag as 0
thread 27 saw flag as 1
thread 28 saw flag as 0
thread 29 saw flag as 1
thread 30 saw flag as 0
thread 31 saw flag as 1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

The above presents a generalized `atomicCAS` for `char` size.  This would allow you to swap any `char` value for any other `char` value.  In your specific case, if you only need effectively a boolean flag, you can make this operation more efficient using `atomicOr` as already mentioned in the comments.  The use of the `atomicOr` would allow you to eliminate the loop in the custom atomic function above.  Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t327.cu
#include <stdio.h>
__device__ char my_char_atomic_flag(char *addr){
  unsigned *al_addr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned *> (((unsigned long long)addr) & (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCULL));
  unsigned al_offset = ((unsigned)(((unsigned long long)addr) & 3)) * 8;
  unsigned my_bit = 1U << al_offset;
  return (char) ((atomicOr(al_addr, my_bit) >> al_offset) & 0xFFU);
}

__global__ void k(){

  __shared__ char flag[1024];
  flag[threadIdx.x] = 0;
  __syncthreads();

  int retval = my_char_atomic_flag(flag+(threadIdx.x>>1));
  printf("thread %d saw flag as %d\n", threadIdx.x, retval);
}


int main(){
  k<<<1,32>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t327 t327.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t327
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
thread 0 saw flag as 0
thread 1 saw flag as 1
thread 2 saw flag as 0
thread 3 saw flag as 1
thread 4 saw flag as 0
thread 5 saw flag as 1
thread 6 saw flag as 0
thread 7 saw flag as 1
thread 8 saw flag as 0
thread 9 saw flag as 1
thread 10 saw flag as 0
thread 11 saw flag as 1
thread 12 saw flag as 0
thread 13 saw flag as 1
thread 14 saw flag as 0
thread 15 saw flag as 1
thread 16 saw flag as 0
thread 17 saw flag as 1
thread 18 saw flag as 0
thread 19 saw flag as 1
thread 20 saw flag as 0
thread 21 saw flag as 1
thread 22 saw flag as 0
thread 23 saw flag as 1
thread 24 saw flag as 0
thread 25 saw flag as 1
thread 26 saw flag as 0
thread 27 saw flag as 1
thread 28 saw flag as 0
thread 29 saw flag as 1
thread 30 saw flag as 0
thread 31 saw flag as 1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

These `char` atomic methods assume that you have allocated a `char` array whose size is a multiple of 4.  It would not be valid to do this with a `char` array of size 3 (and only 3 threads), for example.

Comment: Great. It works correctly. But how can I apply it to use 'char' ? It accepts only int values.

Comment: You can use [atomicOr()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicor) to reduce memory consumption even down to one bit per flag - but you'll have to fiddle with with bitmasks and array offsets.

Comment: @Robert thanks for your detailed answer. It helped me to achieve my target and it works fine now. Thanks !!